# Unable to cast object ... to type

Tags: c#, com, activex

Visual Studio 2008 (C#) created the Interop for my COM objects.  The main objects which I am using are: `OPCHDAServerClass`, `IOPCHDAItems`, and `OPCHDAItem`.  The code is:

```
OPCHDAServerClass server = new OPCHDAServerClass();
server.Connect("OPC.PHDServerHDA.1");
OPCHDAItem item = server.OPCHDAItems.AddItem("MyItem",1);
```

In the third line the `AddItem` method should return an `OPCHDAItem`.  The interop definition for `AddItem` is:

```
[DispId(1610743813)]
OPCHDAItem AddItem(string ItemID, int ClientHandle);
```

The exception that I get is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'OPCHDAServerClass' to type 'IOPCHDAItems'.

I do not understand why I am getting this error message.  `server.OPCHDAItems` implements `IOPCHDAItems`. I do not know why server (`OPCHDAServerClass`) is being cast to `IOPCHDAItems`?

I did initial prototyping in python which worked fine so I know that the COM components are functional.  This is the python code:

```
server = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("Uniformance.OPCHDA.Automation.1")
server.Connect("OPC.PHDServerHDA.1")
item = server.OPCHDAItems.AddItem("MyItem", 1)
```

Has anyone seen a similar issue and know of a work around?

Comment: You say that it's what you're doing in peudo code, but what's you actual code? Also, does OPCHDAServerClass actually have a property called OPCHDAItems?

Comment: Avoid using the type names that end with "Class".  They are synthesized types that don't actually exist in the COM server and can cause trouble like this in some cases.  Try to new a OPCHDAServer or a IOPCHDAServer

Comment: Can you step in to the generated COM?

Comment: The COM objects which I am using were not developed by me.  They are part of a software platform that was purchased.  I just used the "Add Reference" in VS2008 to have VS2008 create the interops for them.  As part of Hans' comment.  The OPCHDAServerClass is what the interop created.  I corrected my question above.  The code listed there is the real code, not pseudo code.  My python code (after running Makepy) was added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the *declared* type of property `OPCHDAItems` is not `IOPCHDAItems` - it's `OPCHDAServerClass`. C# is a statically typed language - it won't typecast COM interfaces unless explicitly told to, and it won't go for the IDispatch unless told to. Rephrase like this:

```
server.Connect("MyServerName");
OPCHDAItem item = (server.OPCHDAItems as IOPCHDAItems).AddItem("MyItem",1);
```

EDIT: try this first:

```
IOPCHDAItems Items = server.OPCHDAItems;
```

Still the same error? How about

```
IOPCHDAItems Items = server.OPCHDAItems as IOPCHDAItems;
```

Comment: Still the same error.  It is still trying to cast the OPCHDAServerClass.  It is behaving like it cannot access the objects within the server object.  I can access properties with simple data types like int and string in server, but not another object.